# PL/SQL error: ORA-01422: Getting 14 blank spaces instead of displaying 14 records

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE displayCondoDetails
AS 
  unitNumber condo_unit.unit_num%TYPE;
  condoFee condo_unit.condo_fee%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT unit_num, condo_fee INTO unitNumber, condoFee FROM condo_unit)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RTRIM(unitNumber)||' '||(condoFee));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Stored Procedure Call

```
BEGIN
displayCondoDetails;
END;
/
```

I am getting 14 blank spaces instead of displaying 14 records.

I am not sure where i am doing something wrong.

[image]

There are only 14 records in this table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAX0E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `select into` statement and a [cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) are two different things. A cursor FOR loop implicitly declares its own record variable from its cursor, so you should not declare your own as it won't be populated. Try something like this:

```
create or replace procedure displaycondodetails
as 
begin
    for r in (
        select unit_num, condo_fee from condo_unit
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(ltrim(rtrim(r.unit_num)||' '||r.condo_fee));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more thing, how can i define column names then?

Comment: Every item in the `select` list (`unit_num` and `condo_fee` in the above example) will be implicitly included in the record (`r` in the above example), if that's what you mean. Essentially the compiler reads the cursor definition and defines a record to match it.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... INTO ...` requires that the query returns exactly one row. If your table contains 14 rows, then either use a condition that selects one out of the 14 rows (cf. example [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm)), or use a cursor for iterating over all the 14 records (cf. example [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php)).

Try something like the following code:

```
...
BEGIN
   FOR condo_unit_rec IN (SELECT * FROM condo_unit)
   LOOP
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RTRIM(condo_unit_rec.unit_num)||' '||(condo_unit_rec.condo_fee));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I am using loop to display my all 14 records but i am getting 14 blank spaces instead of records.